# How to create dynamic textbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to create a textbox dynamically as with the ajax response.

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "data.php",
            type:'POST',
            success: function(data){
                $("#tabb").html("<br>"+data+"</br>");
            }
         });
      });
  </script>
```

data.php

```
$re="select * FROM my_table";
$result=mysql_query($re);
for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {
    $field_info = mysql_fetch_field($result, $i);
    $tbl_str .= "<th>{$field_info->name}</th><br><br>";
}
echo $tbl_str;
```

I want to get text box dynamically as with the ajax results.ie if i have 3 table field then i want 3 text box next to it dynamically.
I want the result as to be like this.

```
name   textbox1
age    textbox2
mark   textbox3
```

Comment: This is **HTML 101**; learn it before diving into the deep end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in PHP,

```
$re="select * FROM my_table";
$result=mysql_query($re);
for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {
   $field_info = mysql_fetch_field($result, $i);
   $tbl_str .= "<tr><td>{$field_info->name}</td><td><input type='text' /></td></tr>";
}
echo $tbl_str;
```